# Long tail distribution of random numbers in Python

Tags: python, random, distribution

I need to make a randomizing function in Python returning values using long tail distribution. Unfortunately, my math skills are nowhere near my programming skills so I'm stuck.

This is the kind of distribution I'm looking for:
[image]
<sub>(source: [danvk.org](https://www.danvk.org/wp/2007-02-11/some-boggle-statistics/index.html))</sub>

Returned value must be between 0 and 1, and it must be possible to assign a peak value (where the graph peaks on the Y axis), which would be a number between 0 and 1.

Example usage:

```
def random_long_tail(peak):
    #magic

value = random_long_tail(0.2)
print(value) #outputs i.e. 0.345811242
```

I will be incredibly grateful for any help in solving this issue. Thank you!

Comment: What is the returned value? Normally, in random number generation the returned value is variable's value. If that is between 0 and 1 how can it have a long tail?

Comment: What you are asking basically makes no sense. The x-axis in your picture generally represents the numbers being returned, while the y-axis represents the probability of getting a given number. Everything else seems to indicate something along the lines of a Poisson distribution, which is implemented in scipy.

Comment: @PerlKristian it sounds like you're looking for either a [boltzmann distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maxwell%E2%80%93Boltzmann_distribution) or a [blackbody curve](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Planck%27s_law) shape. Is that correct?

Comment: @[Per Kristian](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4324327/per-kristian) It is not clear what your question is, or what an answer would require to answer your question.

Answer (score 3):

There are quite a few distributions with single peak value and some tail, [log-normal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Log-normal_distribution), [Gamma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_distribution), [Chi<sup>2</sup>](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chi-squared_distribution) to name a few.

Typically, one can pick out `numpy` random module and see what's avalable and how they fit into your problem. Link: http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/reference/routines.random.html

Comment: This is not really an answer. It is more comment/request for clarification. Please post it as such.

Comment: @MadPhysicist `not really an answer.` Of course, it is an answer. There are 10,000ft view questions, which have similar answers, you know that. For example, what are associative data structures. Well, there are quite few of them with this or that properties

Answer (score 0):

You might look into Numpy's [random sampling](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/routines.random.html) options. See which ones are included in the list of [common heavy-tailed distributions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heavy-tailed_distribution#Common_heavy-tailed_distributions).

The [log-normal](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.random.lognormal.html#numpy.random.lognormal) is a nice example. Numpy allows you to specify the mean and standard deviation. You will have to do a bit of algebra to "assign a peak value". This peak is called the "mode".

Comment: This is a comment/suggestion. It is not really clear what OP wants ATM.